# How can I wrap a trait in a structure when a function is called and then remove the wrapper when the function is called again?

Tags: matrix, rust, wrapper, traits, transpose

I'm trying to wrap an arbitrary structure in another, similar to how someone might wrap an input stream into a buffered input stream.

```rs
struct Matrix<T> {
    cols: u32,
    rows: u32,
    data: *mut T,
}

struct MatrixTranspose<T>(/* Some sort of reference to any matrix */);

trait MatrixTrait<T> {
    fn cols(&self) -> u32;
    fn rows(&self) -> u32;

    fn get(&self, col: u32, row: u32) -> &T;
    fn get_mut(&mut self, col: u32, row: u32) -> &mut T;
    fn set(&mut self, col: u32, row: u32, val: T);

    fn transpose(&mut self) /* -> Some sort of reference to any kind of matrix*/
    {
        // Somehow return MatrixTranspose(self)
    }
}

impl<T> Matrix<T> {
    fn new(cols: u32, rows: u32) -> Self {
        Matrix {
            cols,
            rows,
            data: Vec::<T>::with_capacity((rows * cols) as usize).as_mut_ptr(),
        }
    }
}

impl<T> MatrixTrait<T> for Matrix<T> {
    fn cols(&self) -> u32 {
        self.cols
    }

    fn rows(&self) -> u32 {
        self.rows
    }

    fn get(&self, col: u32, row: u32) -> &T {
        assert!(col < self.cols && row < self.rows);
        unsafe { &*self.ptr.add((row * self.cols + col) as usize) }
    }

    fn get_mut(&mut self, col: u32, row: u32) -> &mut T {
        assert!(col < self.cols && row < self.rows);
        unsafe { &mut *self.ptr.add((row * self.cols + col) as usize) }
    }

    fn set(&mut self, col: u32, row: u32, val: T) {
        self.get_mut(col, row) = val;
    }
}

impl<T> MatrixTrait<T> for MatrixTranspose<T> {
    fn cols(&self) -> u32 {
        self.0.rows()
    }
    fn rows(&self) -> u32 {
        self.0.cols()
    }

    fn get(&self, col: u32, row: u32) -> &T {
        self.0.get(col, row)
    }
    fn get_mut(&mut self, col: u32, row: u32) -> &mut T {
        self.0.get_mut(col, row)
    }
    fn set(&mut self, col: u32, row: u32, val: T) {
        self.0.set(col, row, val)
    }

    fn transpose(&mut self) /* -> Some sort of reference to any kind of matrix*/
    {
        // Somehow return self.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = Matrix::new(3, 4);
    let mut b = a.transpose();
    a.set(1, 2, 4.0_f32);
    b.set(2, 1, 8.0_f32);

    println!("{}", a.get(1, 2)); // 8.0
    println!("{}", b.get(2, 1)); // 8.0
}
```

The point of concern is the `transpose` function.

I thought a good way would be to wrap the original matrix in a transpose view of it, and to unwrap that transpose view if the transpose function is called on that very view.

In the main function, `B` should only live as long as `A`, and become invalid if `A` is somehow dropped before itself. `A` should also be accessible while `B` exists.

I think there should be a way for this to be guaranteed at compile time, but how?

I mainly work with languages that use a garbage collector, and I'm trying to figure out what kind of things are possible with Rust.

Comment: Your implementation leaks and accesses uninitialized memory. There's no reason to use a pointer here - just keep the Vec. Is transpose supposed to return a new matrix or transpose the matrix in place?

Comment: When you define a method i.e. `fn func(&self)` or `fn func(&mut self)` and try to return a reference, it must live as long as the instance lives. Why not just return a new vector?

Comment: Actually, its even worse - the vector you allocate is dropped when `new` returns, so `data` points to a freed memory segment. Don't dive into Rust unsafe features right off the bat - you need to know how RAII, moving, etc works beforehand.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I know it isn't strictly necessary, but what I do with the vec is actually for a reason. Vec keeps track of it's length, and I don't need it's length. Cols and rows is enough to determine that. So what I'm doing is basically just another way of allocating some memory.

And transpose is not supposed to affect the matrix or create a new one. Rather it returns another matrix "view", that wraps the initial one, and flips the row and column when that transposed view matrix is accessed.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Ah I didn't think of that memory segment being dropped... I saw this being used somewhere and I thought it'd be a clever way to get some memory allocated until the allocator api really becomes a part of rust.

Comment: Do you mean [something like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7ddcb5be67d65a6e1f72b15f2801e040)?

Comment: Slimming down the overhead of a `Matrix` would be a noble goal if you were going for high performance, but if you are going for high performance, you should use a third party library that other people have spent time optimizing already. To directly answer your question, you need another struct (say, `Transposed<'a, T>`) that takes a reference to a matrix and does the coordinate shift in its implementation of `Matrix`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yeah that looks like it. Seeing that I'm actually not sure what I'm struggling with this far...

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Well I'm not so much looking for the performance, rather I'm looking into possibilities. And yeah what you're saying is basically the implementation I was going for, yet I was still running into some issues. The biggest one being that I wanted a default implementation for transpose, and so I decided to put a default type Transpose in the matrix trait. The compiler told me I couldn't, cause default types are experimental or something.

Answer (score 1):

This is the design I would have gone for, for the first attempt:

```rust
trait Transposable<'a>
where
    Self::Transposed: 'a,
{
    type Transposed;

    fn transpose(&'a mut self) -> Self::Transposed;
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Transposable<'a> for Matrix<T> {
    type Transposed = MatrixTranspose<'a, T>;

    fn transpose(&'a mut self) -> MatrixTranspose<'a, T> {
        MatrixTranspose { borrowed: self }
    }
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Transposable<'a> for MatrixTranspose<'a, T> {
    type Transposed = &'a mut Matrix<T>;

    fn transpose(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut Matrix<T> {
        self.borrowed
    }
}
```

Full [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9b96d8ce782efacdc7520f9cca1d5504) (I also replaced your undefined behavior with just simply using a vector.)

Comment: At least this is one way to do it. Notice how the commented-out lines in the main function don't compile because that would mean two mutable borrows at the same time.